# How to throttle onWheel events in a React functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, throttling

I have this React*emphasized text* component that I want to do something when a wheel event occurs. But I also want to throttle the wheel events and make sure only one event will trigger the function for two seconds. I am using the throttle function from lodash library.

However, it still fires lots of events and all of them will be executed. I think the cause is that every wheel event produces a unique throttled function. But I have no idea how to make solve the issue and make it work as expected. Could anyone provide me any possible solutions?

Any comments would be appreciated.

```
  const changePage = (direction) => {
    if (direction > 0) {
      console.log("scroll down");
    } else {
      console.log("scroll up");
    }
  };
  const onWheel = (event) => {
    changePage(event.deltaY);
  };
    
  <div className="name" onWheel={_.throttle(onWheel, 2000)} >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `useMemo` with an empty dependency array so that the `_.throttle` is only called once, on mount:

```
const changePage = (direction) => {
  if (direction > 0) {
    console.log("scroll down");
  } else {
    console.log("scroll up");
  }
};
const onWheel = (event) => {
  changePage(event.deltaY);
};
const onWheelThrottled = useMemo(() => _.throttle(onWheel, 2000), []);
```

```
<div className="name" onWheel={onWheelThrottled} >
```

Live snippet:

```js
console.error = () => void 0;
const App = () => {
  const changePage = (direction) => {
    if (direction > 0) {
      console.log("scroll down");
    } else {
      console.log("scroll up");
    }
  };
  const onWheel = (event) => {
    changePage(event.deltaY);
  };
  const onWheelThrottled = React.useMemo(() => _.throttle(onWheel, 2000), []);
  return <div className="name" onWheel={onWheelThrottled} />
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```css
.name {
  height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class="react"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried the solution you provided, but the problem still exists, it still fires thousands of function at one time, I am not quite sure how useMemo works

Comment: Are you sure you're passing the empty dependency array as a second argument to `useMemo`?

Comment: Works just fine here - see live snippet I edited into the answer

Comment: Yeah, I did not add the empty array. Now it works like a charm. Many thanks.